# Why is "pickle" and "multiprocessing picklability" so different in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

Using Python's `multiprocessing` on Windows will require many arguments to be "picklable" while passing them to child processes.

```
import multiprocessing

class Foobar:

   def __getstate__(self):
       print("I'm being pickled!")

def worker(foobar):
   print(foobar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Uncomment this on Linux
    # multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

    foobar = Foobar()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(foobar, ))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

The documentation [mentions this explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods) several times:

> **Picklability**
>
> Ensure that the arguments to the methods of proxies are picklable.
>
> [...]
>
> **Better to inherit than pickle/unpickle**
>
> When using the *spawn* or *forkserver* start methods many types from `multiprocessing` need to be picklable so that child processes can use them. However, one should generally avoid sending shared objects to other processes using pipes or queues. Instead you should arrange the program so that a process which needs access to a shared resource created elsewhere can inherit it from an ancestor process.
>
> [...]
>
> **More picklability**
>
> Ensure that all arguments to `Process.__init__()` are picklable. Also, if you subclass `Process` then make sure that instances will be picklable when the `Process.start` method is called.

However, I noticed two main differences between "`multiprocessing` pickle" and the standard `pickle` module, and I have trouble making sense of all of this.

---

#### `multiprocessing.Queue()` are not "pickable" yet passable to child processes

```
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def worker(queue):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()

    # RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
    pickle.dumps(queue)

    # Works fine
    process = Process(target=worker, args=(queue, ))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

#### Not picklable if defined in "**main**"

```
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Process

def worker(foo):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Foo:
        pass

    foo = Foo()

    # Works fine
    pickle.dumps(foo)

    # AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Foo' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'C:\\Users\\Delgan\\test.py'>
    process = Process(target=worker, args=(foo, ))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

---

If `multiprocessing` does not use `pickle` internally, then what are the inherent differences between these two ways of serializing objects?

Also, what does "inherit" mean in the context of multiprocessing? How am I supposed to prefer it over pickle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a `multiprocessing.Queue` is passed to a child process, what is actually sent is a file descriptor (or handle) obtained from [`pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe), which must have been created by the parent before creating the child.  The error from `pickle` is to prevent attempts to send a `Queue` over another `Queue` (or similar channel), since it’s too late to use it then.  (Unix systems do actually support sending a pipe over certain kinds of socket, but `multiprocessing` doesn’t use such features.)  It’s expected to be “obvious” that certain `multiprocessing` types can be sent to child processes that would otherwise be useless, so no mention is made of the apparent contradiction.

Since the “spawn” start method can’t create the new process with any Python objects already created, it has to **re-import** the main script to obtain relevant function/class definitions.  It doesn’t set `__name__` like the original run for obvious reasons, so anything that is dependent on that setting will not be available.  (Here, it is *un*pickling that failed, which is why your manual pickling works.)

The *fork* methods start the children with the parent’s objects (at the time of the fork only) still existing; this is what is meant by inheritance.

Comment: I am confused. The documentation says ‘When using the spawn or forkserver start methods […]. Instead you should arrange the program so that a process which needs access to a shared resource created elsewhere can inherit it from an ancestor process.’, but you say that the spawn start method cannot use inheritance.

Comment: @Maggyero: I *think* it’s saying that `fork` is better in that you can inherit more, but it’s far from clear, especially since it also uses “inherit” to refer to the limited copying of file descriptors into a child process on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My current understanding is that *all* start methods (fork, spawn, and forkserver) inherit the objects from the parent process, except unnecessary file descriptors in the case of spawn and forkserver. No serializing involved so far. In addition, the `Process` object that created the child process in the case of spawn and forkserver seems to be deserialized in the child process [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L126) and its `_bootstrap` (so `run`) method is called, requiring the `Process` object to be serializable.

Comment: @Maggyero: `spawn` doesn’t inherit any Python objects, which is why you have to engineer `__main__` into recreating them.  `forkserver` inherits them as of the time the server was started.

Comment: `Popen._launch` in [popen_fork.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py#L62-L79), [popen_spawn_posix.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py#L38-L72), [popen_spawn_win32.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py) and [popen_forkserver.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_forkserver.py#L41-L59) confirm your interpretation: fork inherits all Python objects, the others only the read & write file descriptor ends of two pipes.

Comment: For non fork, the pipes are created in the parent process before spawning the child process to let the parent process serialise and write the `Process` object and its environment `sys.path`, `sys.argv`, `os.getcwd()`, `get_start_method()`, `current_process().name`, `current_process().authkey`, `util._log_to_stderr`, `multiprocessing.util._logger.getEffectiveLevel()`, and `sys.modules['__main__'].__spec__.name` or `sys.modules['__main__'].____file__` (cf. [`get_preparation_data`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.2/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L150-L194) in `multiprocessing.spawn`).

Comment: The child process can then read and deserialise the data, set up the environment, including replace the module `__main__` with a new module populated by executing the parent’s module as `'__mp_main__'` so ignoring `if __name__ == '__main__':` blocks (cf. [`prepare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.2/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L265-L290) in `multiprocessing.spawn`), and finally call the method `_bootstrap` (which calls `run`) of the `Process` object (cf. [`_main`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.2/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L120-L129) in `multiprocessing.spawn`).

Comment: Thanks David for this great answer. Do you mind having a look at and answering a very similar question about events rather than queues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380239/how-is-a-multiprocessing-event-passed-to-a-child-process-under-the-hood?