# How is a multiprocessing.Event passed to a child process under the hood?

Tags: python, events, multiprocessing, pickle

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912846/why-is-pickle-and-multiprocessing-picklability-so-different-in-python/56916787#56916787), when a `multiprocessing.Queue` is passed to a child process, what is actually sent is a file descriptor (or handle) obtained from [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe), instead of pickling the `Queue` object itself.

How does this work with `multiprocessing.Event`, e.g. when doing a

```
cancel_event = multiprocessing.Event()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_function, args=(cancel_event, ))
```

I would assume that `Event` must also have some OS-related thing which is sent to the child process. Is this also a handle for a pipe like with queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Event`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9495bcaf599e0961b45447b8fab7f8446945ba1a/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#L328-L365) class is a very simple extension of a `Condition` along with an additional `Semaphore`. A `Condition` contains a `Lock` and a couple more semaphores, and a Lock is just a `Semaphore` with a maximum value of only 1, so the question can really be boiled down to how is a `Semaphore` passed to another process...

---

#### When creating a process using a Spawning context or when sending a lock over a queue or pipe, it is serialized using `pickle`:

The base class for both `Semaphore` and `Lock` is `SemLock`, which defines the [`__getstate__` and `__setstate__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9495bcaf599e0961b45447b8fab7f8446945ba1a/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#L100-L119) methods in order to make it able to be sent across a pipe using the `pickle` protocol.

On the sending side, `__getstate__` will obtain a handle to the lock which can be sent. On Windows one cannot simply take the handle returned by [`CreateSemaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsemaphorea) and use it in another process, so it is instead first duplicated with [`DuplicateHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) giving it the target process where it will be used. On *nix the handle is simply copied.

On the receiving side, the handle number is used along with a unique name and some other attributes which are copied over in order to rebuild the semaphore. This is a pretty simple process of unpacking values into a new `SemLockObject` struct, which contains the handle to the underlying OS level semaphore.

---

#### When creating a process using a Forking context

The new process gets a complete copy of the memory of the parent process, including the objects containing references to the semaphore handles (see: forking and [process copy-on-write](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-on-write/)). As windows is not involved here, the simple copying of the handle value is valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. So basically it is boiled down to passing an integer value that is known/managed by the OS. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Joerg yes, although there is some "permission to use that integer" going on too... In this case windows is more restrictive, requiring extra steps to make a handle sharable.